# Перевод скрипта онлайн радио с NPAPI на HTML5

Tags: html5, google-chrome, wmi

У меня стоял скрипт с проигрыванием потокового радио через NPAPI, но [Плагины NPAPI не работают в Chrome  42 и более поздних версий](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033).

Сам скрипт:

```html
<select name="href" onchange="sel(this.value);">
    <option value="" selected />Выбор радиостанции!
    <option value="http://rfe-channel-04.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/885/229654/v1/ibb.akacast.akamaistream.net/rfe_channel_04.mp3" />Радио Свобода : Русская Служба
    <option value="http://81.19.85.197/echo.mp3" />Эхо Москвы
    <option value="http://95.81.147.3/2587/rfi_en_russe/rfirusse.mp3"  /> RFI  Russian
    <option value="http://www.radioroks.ua/RadioROKS.m3u" />Radio ROKS UA
</select>

<div id="mus" align=center></div>

<script>
    function sel(href)
    {
        if (href == '') 
            mus.innerHTML=""; 
        else 
            mus.innerHTML = "<EMBED type=application/x-mplayer2 src=" + href + " width=225 height=72  showcontrols=1 showdisplay=0 showstatusbar=1>";
    }
    sel(''); 
</script>
```

Хочу сменить Windows Media Player (NPAPI) на HTML5. В общем, на то, что поддерживает Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

[Элемент audio](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio) в помощь.

Чуток подправил исходный код для примера:

```html
<select name="href" onchange="sel(this.value);">
  <option value="" selected />Выбор радиостанции!
  <option value="http://rfe-channel-04.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/885/229654/v1/ibb.akacast.akamaistream.net/rfe_channel_04.mp3" />Радио Свобода : Русская Служба
  <option value="http://81.19.85.197/echo.mp3" />Эхо Москвы
  <option value="http://95.81.147.3/2587/rfi_en_russe/rfirusse.mp3" />RFI Russian
  <option value="http://online-radioroks.tavrmedia.ua/RadioROKS" />Radio ROKS UA
</select>

<div id="mus" align=center></div>

<script>
  function sel(href) {
    if (href == '')
      mus.innerHTML = "";
    else
      mus.innerHTML = '<audio controls autoplay><source src="' + href + '" type="audio/mpeg"><source src="' + href + '" type="audio/wav"><source src="' + href + '" type="audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis">Тег audio не поддерживается вашим браузером.</audio>';
  }
  sel('');
</script>
```